# Eclipse is not generating class file

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have created simple java project. and written simple helloWorld program.

```
package com.test.process;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

in console, I am getting error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.process.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.process.HelloWorld
```

I do not understand why its giving such error. please help me

Comment: Do you see any error in the problems tab (Window > Show View > Problems)?

Comment: @akarnokd there is no error

Comment: Did you install a proper JDK? Did you set it up as the project JDK? (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs).

Comment: This is already answered. Can you check this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: @VivekRautcould you please highlight solution

Comment: @akarnokd yes its installed, via terminal i am able to compile

Comment: How are you running this code? Is it inside a maven or gradle project?

Comment: Right click on the file, select Run As -> Run Configurations and check the classpath tab. Make sure the current project is in it. Check the build path of the project (right click on project) and make sure everything is ok there.